# ¿Como saber qué función llama a otra en oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-11g

Hay alguna manera de saber en PL/SQL de Oracle qué función ha llamado a una función que da error?

Por ejemplo tenemos este código.

```
FUNCTION f_primera() RETURN NUMBER IS

BEGIN
    n := f_segunda;
END f_primera;

FUNCTION f_tercera() RETURN NUMBER IS

BEGIN
    n := f_segunda;
END f_tercera;

FUNCTION f_cuarta() RETURN NUMBER IS

BEGIN
    n := f_segunda;
END f_cuarta;

FUNCTION f_segunda() RETURN NUMBER IS
    num NUMBER;
BEGIN
    ----Esto da error
    num := 'a';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        --Quiero mostras si ha sido llamada por f_primera, f_tercera o f_cuarta
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('xxxx');
END f_primera;
```

La cuestión es que tengo una función que me está fallando porque se le está pasando un parámetro mal, pero es llamada desde muchos packages y funciones diferentes. Querría saber si hay alguna instrucción de oracle que me indique qué función la ha llamado.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas habilitar el rastreo de ejecución de código PL/SQL por medio del paquete `DBMS_TRACE`

Este paquete te permitira hacer trace de llamadas PL/SQL (calls) que es lo que tu necesitas, tambien te permite hacer trace de SQL y exepciones.

**IMPORTANTE: DEBES TOMAR EN CUENTA QUE EL TRACE LO DEBES ACTIVAR DURANTE PERIODOS CORTOS, DEPENDIENDO DE LA TRANSACCIONALIDAD DE TU BD LAS TABLAS DE TRACE PUEDE CRECER DESPROPORCIONALMENTE**

Muy bien aclarado lo mas importante vamos al paso a paso.

La implementacion de este rastreo consta basicamente de lo siguiente:

1. Crear las tablas donde el paquete `DBMS_TRACE` escriba la salida. Para crear estas tablas, ejecuta el script  `tracetab.sql` desde el directorio `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin`

Luego de ejecutado el script, ejecuta la siguiente consulta para verificar la creacion de las tablas:

Consulta:

```
select owner, object_name, object_type 
    from dba_objects where object_name like 'PLSQL%'
    order by 2, 1;
```

La salida deberia ser algo como esto:

```
    OWNER  OBJECT_NAME            OBJECT_TYPE
    ------ ---------------------- -------------
    SYS    PLSQL_TRACE_RUNNUMBER  SEQUENCE
    SYS    PLSQL_TRACE_EVENTS     TABLE
    SYS    PLSQL_TRACE_RUNS       TABLE
```

2. (Opcionalmente) Puedes hacer publico el acceso a las tablas de trace.

   ```
   grant select on PLSQL_TRACE_EVENTS to public;
   grant select on PLSQL_TRACE_RUNS to public;
   ```
3. Indicar el nivel de trace o el tipo de trace que necesitas que ejecute el paquete. Este paquete te permitira hacer basicamente 3 niveles o tipos de trace, serian:

**Trace calls**

```
TRACE_ALL_CALLS – Recoge todas las llamadas a codigo PL/SQL
TRACE_ENABLED_CALLS – Recoge solo llamadas de programas con la opción DEBUG
```

**Trace sql**

```
TRACE_ALL_SQL – Recoge todas las llamadas SQL
TRACE_ENABLED_SQL – Recoge solo llamadas de SQL con la opción DEBUG
```

**Trace exceptions**

```
TRACE_ALL_EXCEPTIONS – Recoge todas las Exepciones
TRACE_ENABLED_EXCEPTIONS – Recoge solo las exepciones con la opción DEBUG
```

Ya identificado el trace que necesitas, que en tu caso seria el trace a llamadas de codigo PL/SQL, puedes iniciar el trace con el siguiente código:

```
    begin
        dbms_trace.set_plsql_trace(dbms_trace.TRACE_ALL_CALLS);
     end;
      /
```

Y para finalizar, con el siguiente código detienes la ejecución del trace y escribe los eventos en las tablas:

```
    begin
          dbms_trace.clear_plsql_trace;
        end;
        /
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Genial @Cerveza, recuerda que, si la respuesta ha sido de tu utilidad debes marcala como aceptada y dar un voto a favor. En este [ENLACE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) muestra como hacerlo. Saludos!